# How to compare date in a jpql query

Tags: jpa, jpql

Hi I want to list all the current records in my database where the date belong to the current month.

```
where d.jourvisite BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

this is my function

```
    public List<Visite> getvisiteDétaillé() {
    Calendar MyEnddate;
    MyEnddate = Calendar.getInstance();
    MyEnddate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    TypedQuery<Visite> query;
    query =
    em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Visite v JOIN v.datevisiteList d where d.jourvisite BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate", Visite.class);
    query.setParameter("startDate",Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    query.setParameter("endDate",MyEnddate,TemporalType.DATE);
    System.out.println("date actual"+Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    System.out.println("date After 30 days"+MyEnddate.getTime());
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I'm sure that i have some records in the DB that are suitable for the query but when I display the result nothing to display with no syntax error

Comment: with "with no syntax error" you mean: no error or exception at runtime?

Comment: yes!! no error..just what i write in the system.out

Comment: pls edit the original question as it might confuse people otherwise

Comment: and the SQL invoked is ? (in the log of the JPA provider).

Answer (score 1):

In the javadoc for [`TemporalType.DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#DATE) they mention:

> Map as `java.sql.Date`.

but you are passing in a `Calendar` for `endDate` parameter.

Just pass in the `Date` instance like you do for the `startDate` parameter:

```
query.setParameter("endDate", MyEnddate.getTime());
```

PS You should follow the most used [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) to make the code more readable.